# Facebook like requests model. Many-to-many with the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :sent_requests, :foreign_key => :sender_id, :class_name => "Request"
has_many :recieved_requests, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, :class_name => "Request"
```

and a requests model:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", :source => "sender_id"
belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", :source => "recipient_id"
```

Im struggling to understand the difference of :foreign_key, :through, :source, :class_name, etc.

This seemed to be slightly different from most tutorial examples because a User can belong to a relationship on both sides (although not at the same time).

Any advice for how to get this working. And more importantly how to think about the relationship?

fyi:
my Request model just has sender_id, recipient_id, and accepted:boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm using:

In user's model:

```
has_many    :sent_requests,
            :class_name => "Request",
            :foreign_key => "sender_id"

has_many    :received_requests,
            :class_name => "Request",
            :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
```

In request's model:

```
belongs_to :sender,
         :class_name => "User"

belongs_to :receiver,
         :class_name => "User"
```

Note that we user :class_name to specify the name of the class when rails cannot infer the name of the class. If you say:
has_many :requests
then you don't need to include the class name. Rails will automatically know that it is Request. But if you want to rename :request to something like :sent_request, you need to specify the class.

Also note that the foreign key is by default guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix. So a class that defines a belongs_to :person association will use “person_id” as the default :foreign_key. You need to specify the foreign_key if you are using a name that does not satisfy rails naming convention.